# What does not int(x) do?

Tags: python, boolean-expression

I have trouble understanding the meaning of `not` in a statement such as

```
not int(x)
```

It evaluates to `True` if `x` is equal to `0`.
But if `x` is any other number it evaluates to `False`.

I would like an explanation for this behavior, thanks.

Comment: _"I am unable to get the meaning of not in this"_. Sorry, in what? If you're confused by a piece of code, please post that piece of code. (preferably as a [mcve])

Comment: if `x` is `0`, `'0'`, or `x` is a float and `1 > x >= 0` then `not int(x)` will be `True`. Otherwise it will be `False`.

Comment: @Kevin should be comprehendible now.

Answer (score 4):

`not some_object` will return `True` if `some_object` is falsy, i.e. if `bool(some_object)` will return `False`.

For any integer `z`, `bool(z)` will always be `True` unless `z==0`. So `not int(x)` is just a way of checking whether `x`, after you convert it to an integer (using `int`), is zero.

Demo:

```
>>> x = '-7' # this is not 0 after conversion to an integer
>>> bool(int(x))
True
>>> x = '0'
>>> bool(x) # a non-empty string is truthy
True
>>> bool(int(x))
False
>>> not int(x) # you can omit the call to bool in a boolean context
True
```

In a boolean context, we can omit the call to `bool`. Using the implicit booleanness of objects can come in handy, especially when you want to check if some object is empty (such as empty strings, sets, lists, dictionaries...).

```
>>> not {}
True
>>> not []
True
>>> not set()
True
>>> not ''
True
>>> not tuple()
True
>>> not 0.0
True
>>> not 0j
True    
>>> not [1,2,3]
False
```

The methods involved here are `__nonzero__` for Python2 and `__bool__` for Python3. Theoretically, we could override these. Consider the following Python2 example:

```
>>> class LyingList(list):
...     def __nonzero__(self): # for Py3, override __bool__
...         return True
... 
>>> liar = LyingList([])
>>> liar
[]
>>> not liar
False
```

uh oh!

Comment: For completeness, an empty tuple, 0.0 and 0j are also falsy.